# Python Matplotlib FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Hello Dear StackOverfloooow Members,
I am having trouble understanding the FuncAnimation module of matplotlib. Would you mind helping me out a bit? I have two questions:

1. Why does both die `init` and `animate` function need a comma after giving back only `PLOT`?
2. Why does my code not update the `time_text`? If I let it print t after every animation i corectly adds one up in console, but the text does not get updated in the plot.

.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
sub = fig.add_subplot(111,xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 1))
PLOT, = sub.plot([],[])
time_text = sub.text(1,1,"",transform = sub.transAxes, ha="right")
t = 0

def init():
    PLOT.set_data([],[])
    time_text.set_text("")
    return PLOT,time_text

def animate(i):
    global t
    x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
    y = np.exp(- ((x-0.01*i)/(2))**2 )/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
    t += 1

    PLOT.set_data(x,y)
    time_text.set_text("time = "+str(t))
    return PLOT, time_text

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=2000, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Not really sure what you mean.  In both `init` and `animate` you need to return both `PLOT` and `time_text`, so you seperate them with a comma so each function will return a tuple.

For the 'hanging' comma in `PLOT, = sub.plot([],[])`, `sub.plot` is returning a list with a single element, a `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` object.  The `PLOT,` is unpacking this single element list. So, you can also do this:

```
PLOT = sub.plot([],[])[0]
```

To get the element.

2) Your code does update `time_text`, you are just drawing it out of the bounds of the graph.  For example change:

```
time_text = sub.text(1,1,"",transform = sub.transAxes, ha="right")
```

To:

```
time_text = sub.text(1,0,"",transform = sub.transAxes, ha="right")
```

To get it to display in the bottom right, or `0.5, 0.5` to get it to display in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Okay, I understand, thank you very much. About the comma thing: For example, if I completly omit the time display and only return the new plotdata: `return PLOT` i get an error. But if I return `return PLOT,` it works. why is that?

Comment: `PLOT,` unpacks what's in `PLOT`. Try this at the console: `a, = [1]`. Then print `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers do not entirely answer the first question.

The return statement of `init` and `animate` is needed strictly only when `blit=True` is used. Those functions are expected to return an iterable of artists to update for the animation. Having two artists, the return could look like

```
return artist1, artist2
# or 
return [artist1, artist2]
```

If a single artist shall be updated, one has to remember that still an iterable is needed. Using the comma after that single artist is then just the easiest way to make the function return an iterable

```
return artist1,
# or 
return [artist1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python tuples are written using parentheses and commas, e.g. (3,2)
which is a 2-tuple. A one tuple would be (2,) which has length 1. This is distinguished from the int 2 which does not have length defined at all.
Note: () is the 0-tuple with empty content.

In this case the function returns an enumerable of length one, so
omitting the comma would make PLOT an enumerable. With the comma sign
the contents of the tuple PLOT, are matched to the contents of the returned value.

Parentheses can be omitted in assignments, so PLOT, is the same as (PLOT,).